# Can i set more than one scroll bar to frame in swing

Tags: swing

I want to set more than one  vertical scroll bar to frame in swing. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a [ScrollPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) to every panel you want.

Comment: Can i divide frame in to parts?

Comment: Yes, just define a JPanel for each part.